# Google +1 button not opening "share this" bubble

Tags: javascript, html, google-plus-one

I'm having some strange behavior with google plusone button.

When a user clicks +1 button, I expect the "share this" bubble to open, but it wasn't opening, so I stripped everything from my page, removed all unnecessary html/css/js and get this page with only google+1 button

http://demo.benimgibi.net/dikkat-ne-kadar-renk-o-kadar-vitamin/?v=1

works fine as expected, then I add a jpg to the code

```
<img height="250" width="650" alt="" src="http://www.benimgibi.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/gj1u0tfwyjmtwfv7.jpg" />
```

and it wont work, you can see here: http://demo.benimgibi.net/dikkat-ne-kadar-renk-o-kadar-vitamin/?v=2

What is even more strange is, if I change the width of the image to a very small number, say 50, it works again.

you can see that version here: http://demo.benimgibi.net/dikkat-ne-kadar-renk-o-kadar-vitamin/?v=3

**NOTE:** +1 works fine in all cases, but Share bubble doesn open at version 2. What I mean with "Share bubble" is

[image]

Comment: I'm using Safari on an iPad, and I don't even get a +1 button!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it is opening in all the cases.
Yeah but for `version-2` it is taking few extra seconds to respond.

But anyways,

> Your picture cannot be the reason behind it.

So keep that out of mind, there may be other reasons for late response.

Comment: for me, it never opens the bubble. At console I can see the response from google, it +1's as it should, it just doesn't open the bubble. I agree, it cannot have anything to do with the picture but as I said I stripped everytihn and left the picture as an example, some hrml code seems always break the button, I don't understand why or how.

Comment: Wait at least 10-12 sec with your mouse on +1 button, it will respond automatically..for me it takes 10 sec...Secondly, I am not at all agreed with your statement "`some html code seems always break the button`", as +1 button only depends upon javascript and your page's `meta` tags.

Comment: yes you are right, but i stripped every js from the page except google's, and added meta tags as google requested. Anyway, if everybody except me can see the bubble, probably it has something to do with my computer/cache/network, I dont know, I dont see any point to waste more time on the problem. Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1):

For me, bubble work in both cases.

Try to clean cache of your browser after update (or use another) and check again. Sometimes javascript scrpits may be blocked, when data from cache don't correspond to data from page.

Comment: two cases? there are three in fact. You sure you tried version 2. I tried it on Firefox, Chrome, Opera and IE9, and also made some friends try on their computers as well.

Comment: I saw only the buuble, in both (first and second link) cases. In the case no. 3 also everything look correct. I don't have a google+ account.